# Spring integration - XpathPayloadEndpointMapping - Not able to understand and no such documentation

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.XPathPayloadEndpointMapping">
    <property name="expression"><value>local-name(/*)</value></property>
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
                <prop key="sampleKey">mySampleServiceGateway</prop>
```

.
.
.

```
<xs:element name="sampleKey">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
```

.
.

I got the above code from one of your integration project. But I am not able to understand what are the possible values the  tag can contain and the meaning of `<value>local-name(/*)</value>`.

Although by seeing the code I could figure it out that the key is the XSD element name but nothing more I could get from this.

are there any documentation related to different mapping for spring integration, how to use them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Bilan for throwing some lights on this.

After doing some kind of more research I realized that the answer , I was looking for is " what are the possible values that expression can use?" and searching all over in spring documentation. -- uff!  I was wrong.

XPath is not a spring element , it is completely an independent element and spring is just utilizing that. So to find out what are the possible values that element can hold, anyone can refer the below link from W3C.

https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-local-name

So. In my case the current value `local-name(/*)` , which is noting but a predefined method of XPath.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks good, although you really need to figure out what XPath expression you should use. It is applied against a SOAP request message body:

```
protected String getLookupKeyForMessage(MessageContext messageContext) throws Exception {
    Element payloadElement = getMessagePayloadElement(messageContext.getRequest());
    return expression.evaluateAsString(payloadElement);
}
```

So, may really consider to assert against a root element of your body.

According to provide configuration you try to resolve to the local name of the root element of the request. Sounds like you are expecting now `sampleKey` as a root tag name.

See JavaDocs of the `XPathPayloadEndpointMapping` for more information.